# How to extract data from XML when some of the child tags and structure are unknown?

Tags: python, xml, xpath

XML be like:

```xml
<Section>
    <ContainerBlockElement>
        <UnorderedList>
            <ListItem>
                <Paragraph>Download the software1 from: <URLLink LinkURL="www.software1.com"</URLLink></Paragraph>
            </ListItem>
        </UnorderedList>
        <UnorderedList>
            <ListItem>
                <Paragraph>Download the software2 from: <URLLink LinkURL="www.software2.com"</URLLink></Paragraph>
            </ListItem>
        </UnorderedList>
    </ContainerBlockElement>

    <ContainerBlockElement>
        <Paragraph>Apply the update in: <URLLink LinkURL="www.update.com"></URLLink></Paragraph>
    </ContainerBlockElement>

    <ContainerBlockElement>
        <Paragraph>Follow these rules:</Paragraph>
            <UnorderedList>
                <ListItem>Don't do this</ListItem>
                <ListItem>Don't do that</ListItem>
                <ListItem>Don't do blablabla</ListItem>
            </UnorderedList>
    </ContainerBlockElement>
</Section>
```

I want to extract all data within `ContainerBlockElement` in text, but the child tags and structure are different every time.

Expected output:

```
Download the software1 from: www.software1.com
Download the software2 from: www.software2.com
Apply the update in: www.update.com
Follow these rules:
Don't do this
Don't do that
Don't do blablabla
```

---

**Update:**
Now I add a new element at the end of the above xml.

```
<ContainerBlockElement>
    <Paragraph>Apply the newer update in: <URLLink LinkURL="www.newerupdate.com"></URLLink></Paragraph>
</ContainerBlockElement>
```

@ACHRAF answer will now output in a messing order. It is order sensitive that can't be use to process different xml files.

```
Download the software1 from: www.software1.com
Download the software2 from: www.software2.com
Apply the update in: www.update.com
Follow these rules:
Apply the newer update in: www.newerupdate.com
Don't do this
Don't do that
Don't do blablabla
```

Expected output should be following the order in the xml. Also the program should be able to distinguish those exist in the same `ContainerBlockElement`. (For example I need to put Follow these rules:, Don't do this, Don't do that, Don't do blablabla in the same array.)

```
Download the software1 from: www.software1.com
Download the software2 from: www.software2.com
Apply the update in: www.update.com
Follow these rules:
Don't do this
Don't do that
Don't do blablabla
Apply the newer update in: www.newerupdate.com
```

Answer (score 2):

First you example contains error in URLLINK

```
<URLLink LinkURL="www.software1.com"</URLLink>
```

will be

```
<URLLink LinkURL="www.software1.com"/>
```

For full example :

```
<Section>
    <ContainerBlockElement>
        <UnorderedList>
            <ListItem>
                <Paragraph>Download the software1 from: <URLLink LinkURL="www.software1.com"/></Paragraph>
            </ListItem>
        </UnorderedList>
        <UnorderedList>
            <ListItem>
                <Paragraph>Download the software2 from: <URLLink LinkURL="www.software2.com"/></Paragraph>
            </ListItem>
        </UnorderedList>
    </ContainerBlockElement>

    <ContainerBlockElement>
        <Paragraph>Apply the update in: <URLLink LinkURL="www.update.com"/></Paragraph>
    </ContainerBlockElement>

    <ContainerBlockElement>
        <Paragraph>Follow these rules:</Paragraph>
            <UnorderedList>
                <ListItem>Don't do this</ListItem>
                <ListItem>Don't do that</ListItem>
                <ListItem>Don't do blablabla</ListItem>
            </UnorderedList>
    </ContainerBlockElement>
</Section>
```

About extraction data you can do like this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
results =  root.findall('ContainerBlockElement/UnorderedList/ListItem') + root.findall('ContainerBlockElement')  + root.findall('ContainerBlockElement/UnorderedList') 
for elem in results:
    for e in elem:
        if (len(e.text.strip()) == 0):
            continue
        URLLINK_Data = e.find('./URLLink')
        if URLLINK_Data is None:
            print(e.text.strip())
        else:
            print(e.text.strip() +" "+ e.find('./URLLink').attrib['LinkURL'])
```

**Output :**

```
Download the software1 from: www.software1.com
Download the software2 from: www.software2.com
Apply the update in: www.update.com
Follow these rules:
Don't do this
Don't do that
Don't do blablabla
```

Comment: Thank you, but this code is order sensitive, may you look at the update?

Comment: Can you edit your post and put your expected result about your last update ?

Comment: Expected output should be following the order in the xml.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the correction mentioned in @ACHRAF's answer, I would also suggest an altenative using lxml instead of ElementTree, because of lxml's better support for xpath:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse('file.xml')
for entry in doc.xpath('//Paragraph'):
    link_target = entry.xpath('./URLLink/@LinkURL')
    ul_target = entry.xpath('./following-sibling::UnorderedList//text()')

    link = link_target[0] if link_target else ''
    ul = " ".join(ul_target) if ul_target  else ''

    print(entry.text,link,ul)
```

Output:

```
Download the software1 from:  www.software1.com 
Download the software2 from:  www.software2.com 
Apply the update in:  www.update.com 
Follow these rules:  
                 Don't do this 
                 Don't do that 
                 Don't do blablabla
```

Comment: Thank you, but this code is order sensitive, may you look at the update?

Comment: @Harry I don't understand your comment: the output seems to be in exactly the same order as the xml? Where's the difference exactly?

Comment: "Apply the newer update in" is in the end of xml, now it is in the middle in the output.

Answer (score 0):

To get the elements that have actual text or URLLink use this XPath

```
/Section/ContainerBlockElement//*[URLLink or text()[normalize-space()]]
```

The `*` symbolises an element-node.

The `[URLLink or text()[normalize-space()]]` is a predicate that filters for elements that have a direct URLLink element or text() as child with has more than just white-space

Then use python to extract both text() and URLLink